# define array-like access member macro in c

Tags: arrays, c, macros

I have a typedef below

```
typedef struct arr_s {
    void** arr;
} *arr_t;
```

Is it possible to define a macro so that it expand like this:

```
arr_t k;
k(i) will expand to k->arr[i];
```

Comment: Did you try the simple `#define k(i) k->arr[i]`?

Comment: OT: Don't hide pointers behind type definitions. And if you absolutely want to, use a type name that reveals the pointer nature.

Comment: #define k(i) will only work if i  have arr_t k if its a different variable like arr_t s it won't work

Comment: Sure, `s(i)` will not work. How would you use a macro without a name? You can try `#define x(a, i) a->arr[i]` and use it by `x(k, i)` or `x(s, i)`. -- Anyway, why would you want to use a macro? Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: In C++ you can implement `operator()` for the structure, but you are using C.

Comment: I'm trying to implement my own vector-like container in c

Comment: Then I would use the C approach: functions, not macros. The preprocessor knows nothing about C, it is a completely different beast. -- If you want to use OOP, each function will receive a pointer to the object, and you can call it `this`.

Comment: What do you mean by that can you give me an example ?

Comment: `void* element(arr_t* this, size_t i) { return (*this)->arr[i]; }` and call it by `element(&k, i);` Do you see, why a pointer type is not a good idea?

Comment: One famous example of this approach is the `FILE` structure. It is opaque to us users, and each function using it gets a pointer to it as the first argument, see `fread()` or `fwrite()`. To construct such an object, you call `fopen()` and you destruct it by `fclose()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't have a macro with varying names or the same name as a variable(that's a basic conflicting symbols error) in C. The best you can do is generate an inline function with a suffix.

```
#define GEN_GET(var) inline var##_get(int i) {return var->arr[i];}
```

When you call `GEN_GET`, it will create an inline function that will be the name of `var` but suffixed by `_get` and returns you what you want by taking in `i`. You can only use it for global variables. If you're using GCC, you could also use this inside functions, which will generate a nested function. Example with a global variable:

```
#define GEN_GET(var) inline var##_get(int i) {return var->arr[i];}
// put declaration of arr here
GEN_GET(arr); // will expand to inline arr_get(int i) {return arr->arr[i];}

int main() {
    arr_get(i); // will inline into arr->arr[i], hopefully.
}
```

Or using GCC, you could put the declare `arr` inside a function but will have to put `GEN_GET(arr)` inside that function as well and won't be able to call the resulting inline function `arr_get()` from anywhere else. These limitations are because of scope issues. You can't even do this in C++, it actually feeds a pointer to the object in it's methods, which is `this`. And you're trying to not feed in the object pointer, improvising on OOP fundamentals.

You should never use this unless the traditional `#define GET(var, i) var->arr[i]` gets too verbose.